# how to design a class having lots of conditions

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have a class which deals with managing medical data. 
I have to calculate some algorithm value but there are lots of conditions. Now I want to place these
codes in a very readable and maintainable way. May be if some design pattern can help but not sure.

Can someone suggest me what is the best way to write the folowing code having so many conditions.

Code snippet:

```
 public MedicalData UpdatePatientData(List<Side> side)
    {
        var medicalData = new MedicalData();

        // if both side available
        if (side[0] == Side.Left && side[1] == Side.Right)
        {
            // if both side valid
            if (IsValid(side[0]) && IsValid(side[1]))
            {
               return medicalData.AlgorithmValue = // here goes some  
                                      //calculation logic and return
            }

            // if only left side valid
            if (IsValid(side[0]))
            {
               return medicalData.AlgorithmValue = // here goes some 
                                //calculation logic and return
            }

            // if only right side valid
            if (IsValid(side[0]))
            {
               return medicalData.AlgorithmValue = // here goes some 
                                   //calculation logic and return
            }
        }

        // if only left side available
        if (side[0] == Side.Left)
        {
            if (IsValid(Side.Left))
            {
                return medicalData.AlgorithmValue = // here goes some 
                               //calculation logic and return
            }
        }

        // if only right side available
        if (side[1] == Side.Right)
        {
            if (IsValid(Side.Right))
            {
              return  medicalData.AlgorithmValue = // here goes some 
                            //calculation logic and return
            }
        }

        return medicalData;
    }
```

Thanks & regards

Comment: I would suggest looking into the chain of responsibility pattern

Comment: This is probably better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). I would note, though, that you may have a bug: your sections marked `// if only left side valid` and `// if only right side valid` both test `side[0]`

Comment: You could just refactor your code in order to have each validation inside a private method. Then, call them in the desired order from your public method. Divide and conquer.

Comment: With the code as shown - it looks like you can simplify things with _if (!(IsValid(Side.Left) && IsValid(Side.Right))) return medicalData;_ straight after creating the instance and then simplifying the rest to _if (both) {} else if (left) {} else {}_

Comment: Books like Refactoring to Patterns are definitely what you should read.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through refactoring to pattern books and it really helped me to scale up my refactoring problems. Thanks again.